# Groupby Row element and Tranpose a Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In Python, I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
     Factor     Value
0    a          1.2
1    b          3.4
2    b          4.5
3    b          5.6
4    c          1.3
5    d          4.6
```

I would like to organize this where:

- unique row identifiers (the factor col) become columns
- Their respective values remain under the created columns

The factor values are not in an organized.

Target:

```
     A     B    C     D
0    1.2   3.4  1.3   4.6     
1          4.5
2          5.6  
3            
4       
5
```

Comment: whats the logic for having 5 rows? is that necessary?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing for me to add. There was no need for rows ```3, 4, and 5``` Additionally, I should have left blanks spaces as ```NaN```.

Answer (score 2):

Use, `set_index` and `unstack` with `groupby`:

```
df.set_index(['Factor', df.groupby('Factor').cumcount()])['Value'].unstack(0)
```

Output:

```
Factor    a    b    c    d
0       1.2  3.4  1.3  4.6
1       NaN  4.5  NaN  NaN
2       NaN  5.6  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!